# Google Maps iOS Select All Markers

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is it possible to select all markers at a time to show all info windows? 
This is what I tried but it just selects the last object in the array..

If not possible, what is the alternative?

```
for (GMSMarker *marker in markersArr) 
        [self.mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
```

PS: I am using Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.7.2.7908

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can only display one info window at a time.

An alternative might be to use custom markers, which contain both the marker and the info window (which you'd need to render yourself into the marker image).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: OK I got it.. I created a UIView which contains everything I need.. Then converted it to UIImage and added it to marker.icon..